# Selenium and JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, selenium-webdriver

When I a generate SelectOneMenu with JSF2.0 the the id I specified in the xhtml is attached to a generated ID from JSF.

e.g. out of `my_fancy_id` it generates `j_idt9:my_fancy_id`

Now I want to test my page with Selenium 2 Web Driver. I try to re-find my select menu:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("my_fancy_id"));
```

Of course it does't find anything because the id is changed. What is the best way to find the select menu on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the id of the form is prepended to all element ids inside the form. If you don't set a form id, JSF does it for you (the 'j_idt9'). Solution: Assign an id to your form and try to use the full id in your `findElement`method, e.g.:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
 ...
</h:form>
```

Call it this way:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myForm:my_fancy_id"));
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can add <h:form prependId="false">  so that the id of the form does not get prepended

Answer (score 1):

You set the [component identifier](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29) on controls; the renderers emit the [client identifier](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28%29) to the markup.

This allows JSF to emit valid HTML ids (they must be unique) even in the face of templates and complex controls. A control will be namespaced by any parent that is a [NamingContainer](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) (such as a [form](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html)).

In some containers, the client identifier will be namespaced by the view, but this generally only happens in portlet environments.

Some component libraries (like [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html)) have a `forceId` attribute, but care must be exercised in using them. I wrote a more extensive post on client identifiers [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html).